# Linking to all my Apps on the Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, hyperlink, google-play

I'm using this link below in order to display all of my apps that I've developed:

market://search?q=pub:

My problem is that when the link is clicked in app, it opens the Google Play Store but the title displays as: "pub:Developer Name". I would like it to simply just display as my developer name and not include "pub:" in front.

Can anybody inform me if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of date, you need to use the keyword `pub`. You can't ignore it!

You can take a look at this:

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:Developer+Name+Here")));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Developer+Name+Here")));
}
```